# type of OS for Linux mint 14 Nadia in Oracle Virtual Box?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, linux-mint

I have been unable to create a VM for Linux Mint. Which type of OS should I use to create a Mint VM?

**Specs**

I have Linux Mint, Mate and Cinnamon 32 bit ISO's. I run Windows XP SP 3 with 2 GB RAM.

Answer (score 1):

I normally choose debian 32 or 64 bit.
But since Linux Mint is derived from Ubuntu , choosing Ubuntu may work as well.

This [tutorial](http://ghayzle.hubpages.com/hub/How-to-Install-Linux-Mint-in-VirtualBox) may help.

Comment: I tried that sir. It did not work for me. Can you please suggest a solution?

Comment: @IcyFlame , then there must be some other issue , because in my system i usually choose debian , and linux mint runs fine...

Comment: Sir, What other issue??

Comment: Is my 1 GB ram enough for running mint?

Comment: @IcyFlame even ubuntu can be used as the type , try that

Comment: @IcyFlame ,!GB is more than sufficient

Comment: Ubuntu is also Debian based?

Comment: How much is normally required?

Comment: Yes Ubuntu is based on Debian. Normally 512Mb to 1gb is sufficient , for running a few applications . But i don't see a ram issue here

Answer (score 1):

Here are some VirtualBox appliances with Linux Mint. Try with them. As everyone suggested - both Debian and Ubuntu should do the job. Also be sure that you are using 32 bit OS with 32bit virtual machine and 64 bit OS with 64 bit machine.

Link:
http://virtualboximages.com/VirtualBox.Linux.Mint.vids